# how to prevent re-rendering components with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-loadable

How to prevent component re-rendering, when i have an hierarchical array of objects (array of objects) using redux dispatching and memo
for example i have like this list of list of components
like

```
  Elements =[   // an array in store.state variable
                {name='a',
                 subEelemets:[
                              {name:'a-a', 
                              components:[
                                          {
                                           name:'a-a-1',
                                           component:'TextFiled',
                                            value:'default value...'
                                          },
                                          ]
                               },
                              ]
                 },
               ]
```

i used redux to update components values inside my Elements array using dispatch but the performance downgrades because of many re-rendering,
i tried with memo to prevent re rendering but it also updates the entire Elements array because i used useSelector,

```
  const ImportedComponent = memo((props) => {

  const LoadableComponent = loadable(() =>
  import("../lib" + props.compName)) 
  );

  return (
    <LoadableComponent
      {...props}
       id={props.id}
  
     />)},(a,b)=>a.id===b.id?true:false)
```

here the code how i redner my compoents

```
 const selectTodoIds = state => state.components.map((todo,index) => todo)

 const updateComp = () => {
    const Components = useSelector(selectCompsIds, shallowEqual)
  
    const renderedListItems = Components.map((CompId) =>
       <ImportedComponent key={CompId} elementID={CompId} />
    )
  
    return <ul className="todo-list">{renderedListItems}</ul>
  }
```

it works when i used a flat array as presented in the tutorial https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react  but not for hierarchical one, because i should use the "name" to define which subelement i'm updating,
is there any strategy to solve this problem?
ps: the code is just for clarification,

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `memo` you could try `useMemo`:

```
  const ImportedComponent = (props) => {

    const LoadableComponent = useMemo(() => {
      return loadable(() => import("../lib" + props.compName));
    },[props.compName]);
   
    ...
```

`memo` only helps when there's lots of re-renders with the same props, which it doesn't appear you have.

That's a complete shot in the dark, though. Can you post a link to a stackblitz, maybe? It'd be nice to see more of your code in context.